# Many to Many association in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, model-associations

I have a question which seems is repeated but it's not:

I explain with a small example.

I have two table: **Students** & **courses**.

Each *Student* can take N *courses* and each *course* can be taken by N *students*.

I want to have access the *courses* by *Students* and also have access to *Students* by *courses*.

EX:

1- Give me the list of *courses* that *Student* with id=1 took.

2- Give me the list of *Students* who took the *Course* with id=2000.

If I use **belongsToMany** in *StudentsTable* Class is enough or I should Also define **hasMany** or **belongsToMany** in *CoursesTable* class.

Tell me what should I do.

Thank in advance.

PS: I use CakePHP 3.x

Comment: Go with `hasMany Through`.I recommend to visit the official site of Cakephp. They have provided a great example in https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model

Comment: You are right to use the HABTM relationship. You need a third table that will join students to courses and visa versa. Cakes convention wants you to have `students` table, `courses` table and the connecting table labelled `students_courses`, but really you can name it whatever you want. I usually go with something easy to understand like `student_course_links`. `students_courses` should contain its own primary key and the foreign keys for both students and courses. I feel like the documentation is good enough, but if you need me to explain more i will try

Comment: @Agam Banga, Thanks for the link but it's for CakePHP 2.x.

Comment: @Jason Joslin: I know the third table but I want to know which kind of relation I need.

Comment: I think I should write belongstomany in one of the Model but I want that you conform it.
[belongsToMany](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations)

Comment: @MalusJan Cake 3 also has this document https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option

Comment: @Agam Banga: Tx so much

Comment: @Agam Banga may you give me your email? I have a question.

Comment: @MalusJan, Yes its er.agam16@gmail.com

Comment: @Agam Banga Should I create the CourseMemberships table myself or it will be create by cakePHP automatically

Comment: @MalusJan you need to bake the models for all three in case of HasMany through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Agam Banga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4018629/agam-banga) said in this [link](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option) we should use:

```
class StudentsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Courses', [
            'through' => 'CourseMemberships',
        ]);
    }
}

class CoursesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Students', [
            'through' => 'CourseMemberships',
        ]);
    }
}

class CoursesMembershipsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Students');
        $this->belongsTo('Courses');
    }
}
```